# mqtt paho ws not connected - connection timeout

Tags: javascript, html, xampp, mqtt

I am very new to mqtt and recently is tasked to establish a connection using mqtt broker. I have this mqtt settings all set up, but unable to connect. I get this error every time the connect() function is called `Connection failed: AMQJSC0001E Connect timed out.` I'm running this over Xampp.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var options = {
            timeout: 3,
            userName: "myusername",
            password: "mypassword",
            onSuccess: function () {
                alert("Connected");
                console.log("mqtt connected");
                //Connection succeeded; subscribe to our topic
                client.subscribe(MQTTsubTopic, {qos: 0});
            },
            onFailure: function (message) {
                alert("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
                console.log("connection failed");
            }
        };

        //Create MQTT client here
        var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(MQTTbroker, MQTTport, "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
                        
        client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
            alert("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
            console.log("connection lost");

        /* Connect to MQTT broker */
        client.connect(options);
        };
   </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Here's my MQTT broker and port information which i have defined in another js file. '000.000.00.00' isn't a real broker. What could possibly be wrong in my connection establishment?

```
var MQTTbroker = '000.000.00.00';
var MQTTport = 9001;
```

On the other hand I attempted to connect with a sample broker `broker.emqx.io` with port `8083` and it's connected. I got the example from [this link](https://www.emqx.io/blog/connect-to-mqtt-broker-with-websocket)

Comment: You are 100% sure that the browser this is running on can reach the broker and that it is not running a firewall blocking access to port 9001?

Comment: You're right I've just checked and port 9001 is blocked. But how do i unblock it? Sorry I'm very new to this and appreciate your replies

Comment: That is a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) not Stack Overflow.